# C++ inner classes not compiling

Tags: c++, class, inner-classes

I have a Class called Song with Inner class Creator . Below is the Song.h File. Please ignore the comments.

```
#ifndef SONG_H
#define SONG_H
#include <iostream>


class Song
{
    public:
    class Creator{

        public:
        //Creator& name(const std::string name){};
       void  name(const std::string name){};

        //std::string getName(){};
    };


    private:
    std::string mName;
};

#endif // SONG_H
```

and here is Song.cpp class

```
#include "Song.h"

using std::string;
//using Song::Creator;
//Song::Creator& Song::Creator::name(const string name)
void Song::Creator::name(const string name)
{
  mName=name;
  std::cout<<name;
  //return *this;
}

//string Creator::getName()
//{
  //return mName;
//}
```

and the main class

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Song.h"

int main()
{
Song::Creator sc;
sc.name("vickey");
//std::cout<<sc.getName();

return 0;
}
```

On compilation it throws

```
/home/vickey/qtprojects/innerClass-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_0_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Release/../innerClass/Song.cpp:6: error: redefinition of 'void Song::Creator::name(std::string)'
```

and if I change the name function to

```
void Creator::name(const string name)
{
  mName=name;
  std::cout<<name;
  //return *this;
}
```

I get this error

```
/home/vickey/qtprojects/innerClass-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_0_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Release/../innerClass/Song.cpp:6: error: 'Creator' has not been declared
```

what is that I m doing wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Style advice: short names like `SONG_H` are prone to collide some day, and from experience, header-guard clashes are mighty confusing. Personally, I do `<NAME_OF_FILE_DATETIME>`, e.g. `#ifndef SONG_H_20120330`. Because time is not reversible, this only clashes if you have multiple files of the same name at the same day (in that case, you write `SONG_20120330a` or `SONG_20120330_1959`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the definition from the class declaration:

```
void  name(const std::string name){};
```

change to

```
void  name(const std::string name);
```

The `{}` represents a definition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I wanted to make the inner class access the outer class private variables. Surfing through similar post I have found that Inner classes in C++ need to store a reference to Outer class unlike Java.